# Simple Product Quantity Stopping Grouped Product From Working

Tags: simple-product, grouped-products, magento2.2.0, advanced-pricing

I am running M2.2.0 and have set up a store that only sells 4 products (bottled beer), my problem though is this: The boss only wants to sell them by the case of 8 bottles. I have set up a Simple Product for each beer with a price per bottle and edited the Advanced Inventory to be Min Qty of 8 and incriments of 8 so that customers don't order in values of 6, 10, 3 etc. I am now scatching my head as to how I can now do a mixed case containg 2 bottles of each beer? A grouped product gets rejected at the Cart page due to the quantity of bottles being 2 instead of 8.

Things to note: I'm new to this so please bear with me and accept newbie mistakes. The Simple Products are not visible but I have set up Grouped Products for each beer with a default of 8 bottles.